# OpenCV: Harris in given image points

Tags: opencv

I want to use the Harris corners detector, [check here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cornerharris#cornerharris).

However, this applies the filter to all the image points. I want to apply it to some specific pre-computed point coordinates in the image. How can I do this? Is this possible without rewriting `cornerHarris` myself?

Comment: You want to apply it to a particular part of the image? Use ROI and crop out the bit you want first and then just run Harris on that?

Comment: @GPPK thank you, but I really only want to apply it to a specific set of (x, y) points

Comment: Then copy only those points to a new image and use Harris.